# Issue on Running ASP.Net App on Prod Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g

I am trying to Run an Asp.Net App On second server (Production - Windows Server 2008) I just copied all app folder from Test Server to Production Server but I am getting following error:

[image]

As I said I am using exactly same database and connection string but not sure why this is happening?!
Can you please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472487/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-it-may-not-be-install

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865249/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-it-may-not-be-install

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928361/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 0):

you are clearly missing the driver that your connection string is pointing to.  Install that driver.

Comment: Thanks T McKeown, Can you pleaee just let me know how I can find outwhich driver it is?

Comment: why don't you paste your connection string.  I have to run to meeting....  sorry.

Comment: Do I have to install it on Windows machine or add as refrence to Project?